# OpenCart 2.0.1.1 updates done orders with currency rate

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

This is the code for /admin/controller/sale/order.php:

```
$results = $this->model_sale_order->getOrders($filter_data);

        foreach ($results as $result) {
            $data['orders'][] = array(
                'order_id'      => $result['order_id'],
                'customer'      => $result['customer'],
                'status'        => $result['status'],
                'total'         => $this->currency->format($result['total'], $result['currency_code'], $result['currency_value']),
                'date_added'    => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_added'])),
                'date_modified' => date($this->language->get('date_format_short'), strtotime($result['date_modified'])),
                'shipping_code' => $result['shipping_code'],
                'view'          => $this->url->link('sale/order/info', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&order_id=' . $result['order_id'] . $url, 'SSL'),
                'edit'          => $this->url->link('sale/order/edit', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&order_id=' . $result['order_id'] . $url, 'SSL'),
                'delete'        => $this->url->link('sale/order/delete', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&order_id=' . $result['order_id'] . $url, 'SSL')
            );
        }
```

With this line the total of the order is calculated:

```
'total' => $this->currency->format($result['total'], $result['currency_code'], $result['currency_value']),
```

Now everytime when I update the currency rates, the done orders are changing too! The `$result["total"]` is the right value, but it gets formated with the CURRENT currency rate. Is this a bug? Has anyone experienced this issue, too?

E.G.
Customer has bought products for 200€ at monday with currency 1.2. 
At friday currency rate changed to 1.3. The products in shop are more expensive. That´s nice. But the prices of the product AND the total of the customers order in order history is increasing too. (same in admin)

**EDIT:** 
We have found out that this is the default behavior of opencart. Is there any way to get rid of this dumb feature? Plugins?

Comment: Its the opencart feature. You can find more about it in opencart forums. ad maybe even find a solution

Comment: What a dumb feature is this? I have searched the forums for this but not have found something. Could you plz point out a post?

Comment: Sorry, but I can´t believe that this is a feature

Comment: I am using opencart and works the same as you say

Comment: But if a user comes at another day, to download his invoice, the price is completely different!?

Comment: and hence we stopped using it. We are now setting up user based values in local currency.. so no changing of value.

Comment: Ok. Could you please have a look in your db. The total of an order is it stored incl. taxes or without taxes? E.g. If a users oder is 100, is it stored as 100 in your database?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76167/discussion-between-preeti-maurya-and-m1crdy).

Comment: Did you set up your own table in the end to set your own constant currencies?

Comment: Nope I have not. I have now rewrote the function currency->format() to not add the currency value to the totals